# Google gAnnounce.js not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am working on a site that was developed by someone else. The home page (index.php) runs the Google Announce script - gAnnounce.js.

The owner of the site has reported that the script "is not working in IE8 all of a sudden". The script works in all other browsers I have tried. But it is not working in IE8.

Here is the error I receive when testing in IE8;

*An error has occurred in the script on this page.
Line: 14 Char: 1 Error: 'v_content[...].0' is null or not an object Code: 0 URL: http://teleco4.com/js/gAnnounce.js*

The owner of the site swears it worked before.

Does anyone have any insight or experience with this announcement scroller script issue?

Thanks in advance to all.

**iogen70**

Comment: FYI, looking at the script, I don't think it was developed by Google - it was simply built using techniques found by searching Google.  Do you have the unminified source somewhere, or is what's there all there is?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page where this script is in use, namely [teleco4.com](http://teleco4.com/), your problem seems to be in `v_content` array termination at **line 401**. The problem is **not** in the *gAnnounce.js* script. Here's the relevant part of your code:

```
v_content=[['','\"Without the helpful, knowledgeable people at Teleco,
I would be lost.\" <br> <strong>Carol Coote, NYC Law
Department</strong>',''],['','\"Bravo Teleco. They did a great job for
us, with good communications and stayed until problem fixed. Thanks.\"
<br> <strong>Jay Brill ABC Training Center</strong>',''],['','\"Your
response time was remarkable – as was the good service – with NO down
time whatsoever,\" <br> <strong>Scott Rovner Vendor Lease Management
Group</strong>',''],]
```

**Notice the additional comma after the last declared nested array?! Remove that comma and you should be fine.** Seems IE has problems when arrays are not properly terminated. Your code should be:

```
v_content=[['','\"Without the helpful, knowledgeable people at Teleco,
I would be lost.\" <br> <strong>Carol Coote, NYC Law
Department</strong>',''],['','\"Bravo Teleco. They did a great job for
us, with good communications and stayed until problem fixed. Thanks.\"
<br> <strong>Jay Brill ABC Training Center</strong>',''],['','\"Your
response time was remarkable – as was the good service – with NO down
time whatsoever,\" <br> <strong>Scott Rovner Vendor Lease Management
Group</strong>','']]
```

I've tested this solution locally and it indeed starts working properly in Internet Explorer 8. See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/2rZb5/

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Tidal. I removed the extra "," however it still returned the same error. I've become frustrated beyond belief with this issue.

Comment: @Chris Walker - Well, you haven't! I just checked the source I get on the relevant page in question, and the last comma is still there. I've also tested my suggestion locally and it works in IE8. Check again for that unfortunate comma, remove it and you should be OK. Cheers! ;)